# Change a space to a + in order to complete an api in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I'm trying to make a search form to use on an api. However when the user types in the search field more then one name I want it to break the string into pieces and make a new string with a + between every keyword. I have no idea how to do this however.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var searchString:String = "nameOne nameTwo nameThree";
var whiteSpacePattern:RegExp = /\s+/g;
var replacedString:String = searchString.replace(whiteSpacePattern, "+");
trace(replacedString); // nameOne+nameTwo+nameThree
```

More information about String.replace : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f00.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ef1